# add calcfield to TQuery

Tags: sql, delphi

I found  this code to create a calc field to a TADOTable in Delphi somewhere  ...

```
    .....
    procedure TfrmMain.ABSTable1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
    begin
      with ABSTable1 do
       FieldByName('cost').AsFloat := FieldByName('price').AsFloat *
                                      FieldByName('quantity').AsInteger;
       //  add new field cost as Price * quantity  !!!!
    end;

    end.
```

Inside my app i create a TADOQuery at rum time like

```
  try
    Fquery.sql.clear;
    Fquery.sql.AddStrings(Amemo.lines);
    Fquery.Open;

    .....    
  finally

  end;
```

How to add more calc fields to my Query derived from the first code Fragment ?

Comment: The problem is not adding calculated fields, but a flexibility of formulas you can use. You can make (or find) an expression evaluator that will calculate the values in the `OnCalcFields` event passing the current field values. Without it (or some scripting language), you can only hardcode your formulas there, hence having dynamically added calculated fields makes little sense.

Comment: @TLama:  Good points.  Somewhere on my "idle curiousity" to-do list is to investigate whether the evaluating engine which presumably lurks underneath live bindings can be enlisted for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the only way you can easily do this is by creating a set of persistent TFields in the IDE (or do the equivalent creation of them in code before you open the dataset).  Otherwise, when you call Open on the dataset, IIRC that will call BindFields and that - unless the dataset already has a set of TFields - will create a set of dynamic TFields which will last as long as the dataset is open, but will **not** include any calculated fields.

By the time BindFields has been called, it's too late to add any more, so you have to set them up beforehand or not at all.

Comment: not sure I understood the answer completly.  Where to add the new persistent field : here  FQuery.Fields.Add(newField);

Comment: The easiest way is to right-click the dataset in the IDE, click Fields Editor in the pop-up menu, and right-click the Fields Editor when it pops up.  Or, you can create TFields in code, one-by-one, as in "  AField := TStringField.Create(Self);" in the OnCreate event of a TForm or TDataModule.  It's the field's Owner which provides the persistence.

Comment: I did not placa a Tdatamodule on my form. Just TQuery, DBGrid and TDatasource , thats all i used.

Comment: You can't place a TDataModule on a form, it's a non-visual alternative to a TForm.  It doesn't matter though: If, in the code of your TForm, you use the code I just quoted, the Self refers to the TForm instance - the "AField" has to be a field (in the other sense) of your TForm.